# Qual é a diferença entre "git init" e "git init --bare"?

Tags: git

A pergunta é bem simples mesmo:

Qual é a diferença entre esses dois comandos, `git init`  e `git init --bare`?

Para que serve essa opção `--bare`?

Comment: Esse artigo, ajuda a entender um pouco mais sobre o assunto do Bare. http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Com o comando `git init --bare` você está criando um repositório que é *pushable*. Geralmente os repositórios `bare` são criados no servidor e são considerados repositórios para armazenamento, em contraste aos repositórios que vão nas máquinas dos desenvolvedores que seriam os repositórios de desenvolvimento, criados com o comando `git init` (sem o `--bare`).

Apesar do GIT ser um sistema de controle de versionamento distribuído, é muito comum que exista um repositório central que facilite a troca de informações entre os desenvolvedores, evitando a necessidade que os computadores dos desenvolvedores se comuniquem diretamente entre si.

Uma ilustração do parágrafo acima:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além do mais, repositórios `bare` não possuem *working directory*, tornando impossível editar e commitar arquivos nesse repositório.

Abaixo uma imagem do fluxo dos repositórios GIT dos desenvolvedores (não-`bare`):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: [Atlassian - Setting up a repository](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-init)

Answer (score 11):

**O que é:**

Ao incializar um repositório como **bare** não será permitido editar arquivos (git add) e commitar mudanças (git commit), já que o mesmo não possui uma *working tree*. Você deve atualizar um repositório bare utilizando **git push**.

**Quando é usado:**

Você inicializa um repositório como bare quando deseja que ele seja o respositório central.

Answer (score 4):

Outra diferença entre os repositórios do tipo --bare e do tipo Working Tree é que no primeiro caso **não são armazenados commits perdidos, mas apenas são armazenados commits que pertençam à trilha de um branch**. Veja abaixo...

Criei o primeiro repositório (nome: *git-bare*) com `git init --bare`. Ou seja, ele é o servidor. É o do lado esquerdo, onde não existe branches remotos porque este é o próprio repositório remoto.

Criei o segundo repositório (nome: *git-working-tree*) com `git clone` recebendo do primeiro. Ele é o da direita. Tem branches locais vinculados aos branches remotos.

(Os textos 'first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'alfa', 'beta' e 'delta' são os comentários dos commits. Os nomes 'master' e 'greek' são nomes dos branches.)

[image: Repositório local e remoto]

Agora eu vou apagar o branch chamado 'greek' tanto no *git-bare* (comando: `git push --delete origin greek`) como localmente no *git-working-tree* (comando: `git branch -D greek`). Veja como fica a árvore:

[image: O repositório git-bare apaga o que não é mais referenciado]

O repositório *git-bare* apaga tanto o branch como seus comits. Por isso o nome 'bare' que tem o sentido de puro. Ele só armazena os comits que podem ser referenciados. Na foto vemos que a árvore dele ficou reduzida por este motivo.

Por outro lado, o repositório *git-working-tree*, que equivale a um repositório local que usamos comumente, não apaga os commits, que agora só podem ser referenciados diretamente pelo seu hash com um comando do tipo `git checkout 7fa897b7`. Por isso sua árvore não tem sua estrutura modificada.

**EM RESUMO: commits nunca são descartados em repositórios do tipo *working-tree*, mas são apagados em repositórios do tipo *bare*.**

Em termos práticos, você só consegue recuperar um branch apagado no servidor se ele existir em um repositório local. Isso porque ele e seus commits foram totalmente removidos do servidor.

**Mas é muito estranho que o tamanho do repositório *bare* não diminui de tamanho em disco após excluir um branch remoto. Ou seja, os arquivos ainda estão lá de alguma forma.** Para enxugar o repositório, apagando o que não é mais referenciado ou o que nunca mais pode ser referenciado (este último caso) use o comando `git gc --prune`

Comment: Para treinar comandos Git veja: https://github.com/sergiocabral/App.GitPlayground

Answer (score 3):

**Repositórios Bare**: repositório central armazenado remotamente,  destinado a a integração e compartilhamento em ambientes de colaboração ondes todos podem efetuar alterações por pull ou push sem risco de conflitos,  contém apenas as alterações(commits) e o código fonte armazenado, sem working tree e rastreamento de arquivos.

**Repositórios comum**: repositório local conectado diretamente ao git, usado por desenvolvedores individuais trabalharem ativamente em projetos editando, testando, adicionando ou removendo códigos, cada qual tem as sua própria cópia armazenadas na máquina, as mudanças feitas são detectadas pelo git, possuem área de staging e working tree, ou seja

***Mas qual a necessidade de haver essa distinção?***

Simples, para trabalhos com equipe, é conntra-produtivo que o código esteja armazenado localmente (em uma máquina) visto que pode acontecer problemas técnicos, erros de sincronização. Sendo assim, seria muito mais prático que desenvolvedores usassem um repositório central que será utilizado por todos e sincronizará todas as alterações automaticamente, e criasse um repositório local de trabalho conectados a este

Q**ual a origem do termo "bare"?**

Em suma, significa "leve" ou "nu", uma analogia por conter apenas o essencial, no caso os metadados do repositório

Resumindo,

Os repositórios bare não possuem uma working tree logo, também não possuem área de staging — Github é um exemplo — , só ficam armazenadas as alterações feitas por pull ou push, sendo assim, para adicionar, remover, alterar o código, é necessário usar git push e adicionar a atualização ao repositório. Então, não é possível trabalhar utilizando repositório bare (github), sendo necessário clonar o respositório na máquina e assim poder fazer as possíveis e alterações e depois de feitas, adicionadas ao repositório central, remoto (Bare) via push ou pull